# Cannot install 6.0.7 on OSX El Capitan - .dmg won't open

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac, tor-install

Yesterday I downloaded TorBrowser-6.0.7-osx64_en-US.dmg from torproject.org.  The GPG checks out.  However, it hangs when opening the .dmg file.

- Double-click the .dmg file (or I right-click and select "Open with" diskimagemounter).
- It opens a window saying "Opening TorBrowser-6.0.7-osx64_en-US.dmg".

  - Verifying...  [This completes.]
  - Attaching...  [This hangs.]
- It eventually times out.
  [image: Screenshot of "Attaching..." for Spanish-language download]
  [image: Operation timed out]
- Same errors with the Spanish version.

I am using a MacBook Air, 11" (Early 2015). 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7.

Comment: Has anyone else had success installing 6.0.7 on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what might be causing this issue, since OSX is not giving a precise error message, but I have seen "operation timed out" errors with other dmg files when there is a problem with permissions.

I no longer use OSX, so this is just from memory; please bear with me if the layout or anything like that has changed!

Launch Disk Utility from Utilities.
Select your HD from the left and then select the tab that says either "repair" or "first aid" or something like that.

You should see an option for "Repair Permissions". Select that, and when it's complete it should read "Permissions Repair Complete". Then restart and try to open the dmg file again.

Alison

Comment: Thank you @Alison, I would not have guessed that.  I needed to:  restart in Safe Mode, run Disk Utility, and restart.